# Проблема с установкой MAGENTO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo, magento

Выдает ошибку на 67%, вот лог

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data... 
[ERROR] exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228' in C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'PDOStatement::e...', 'C:\OpenServer\d...', 228, Array) #1 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #2 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #3 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #4 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #5 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `setup_m...', Array) #6 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(452): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE`setup_m...', Array) #7 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(507): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE `setup_m...', Array) #8 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(635): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE`setup_m...', Array) #9 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Module\ModuleResource.php(129): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('setup_module', Array, Array) #10 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(853): Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleResource->setDataVersion('Magento_Configu...', '2.0.0') #11 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(795): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #12 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #13 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #14 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #15 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #16 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #17 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #18 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #19 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #20 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #21 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #23 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #24 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #25 C:\OpenServer\domains\magento\setup\index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main}

Comment: Ну а теперь логи MySQL

Comment: Явно sql падает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this changes in the MySQL Config File:

```
max-allowed-packet              = 1024M
wait-timeout                    = 7200
innodb-log-file-size            = 2047M
innodb-log-buffer-size         = 8M
innodb-log-buffer-size         = 32M
```

And Magento has instaled successfull

Comment: Почему дублируется параметр `innodb-log-buffer-size` с разными значениями?

Comment: Поменял только один параметр `wait_timeout=1800` , этого оказалось достаточно (30 минту) для установки демо данных мадженто 2.